# Trying to get a Border near on JPanel but it's vanishing

Tags: java, swing, border, distance, gridbaglayout

I have a field of little JButtons[15][30] (35px) and I want a border around that field. Now i thought it's enough to write following:

```
 private void gameField() {

    fieldpanel = new JPanel();                 
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

    GridBagLayout bag = new GridBagLayout();       
    fieldpanel.setLayout(bag);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


    fieldpanel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 0, 0, 0), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)));
    fieldpanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
    fieldpanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 500));


    box.add(fieldpanel);

    for (int line = 0; line < field.length; line++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < field[line].length; column++) {
            field[line][column] = new JButton();
            field[line][column].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));   
            field[line][column].setOpaque(true);
            field[line][column].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            field[line][column].setBorderPainted(true);
            field[line][column].setEnabled(false); 
            gbc.gridx = column;
            gbc.gridy = line;
            fieldpanel.add(field[line][column], gbc);

        }
    }

    frame.add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

But look the result:

[image]

You see a part of the field of JButtons, but the border is maybe 10px too high and too wide.

For testing I have placed a red line nearby on the left upper corner. And if I place this line a few more pixel right it is going to disappear. In other words if I am putting the black border closer to the button field then it's going to vanishing.
Notices: I'm using Gridbaglayout for my JPanel (which includes my Jbutton field) and wrapped it into a box.

EDIT:
It's Snake and works well (at the moment). (Only the Problem with the Border exists, look above).
I have added a second image for a better explanation:

http://s10.postimg.org/76rffr2u1/Unbenannt.jpg

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. By default the components on  GridBagLayout will be centered on the panel. Don't hard code sizes. Use pack() on the frame to make sure comonents are displayed at their preferred size. If that doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Look at the picture, what do you see? Correct a black lineborder. I would like to place that Border on the jbutton field but it doesnt work. When I reduce the distance of the border it will disappear. There is an empty GAP between button field and the line and I want to remove that GAP but dont know how.

Comment: I gave you suggestions and asked for a `SSCCE` if the suggestions didn't help. If the hardcode sizes are wrong and the panel is centered it might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The panel is centered but thats ok. I don't see the cause of the gaps between the line and the field. It thinks the gap is part of field but why? At first I thought the causing problem is the emptyborder but it wasn't.

Comment: The problem is with your code and you haven't posted your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem!!! Why do I have to ask 3 times for a `SSCCE`??? Also, why are you using a GridBagLayout? A GridLayout is much easier to use and was specifically designed for a grid of row and columns. Why are you hardcoding sizes? A layout can't do its job properly if you calculate a wrong value. I think your sizes are wrong and the buttons are being centered inside the Border.

Comment: I have used GridBagLayout because I can determine a specific size on the Buttons. GridLayout ignores preferredsizes, it would look different. I couldn't create the same buttons with the same size like in the picture by using gridlayout. Therefore I am using gridbaglayout. Or tell me how can you get with Flowlayout or GridLayout small Buttons with 15 lines and 30 columns symmetric? If I am using flowlayout it cuts the columns and adds to his trail and gridlayout makes the buttons thin (but all sites of a button should have the same length like the picture).

Comment: `GridLayout ignores preferredsizes,` - Then you don't understand how to use layout managers effectively. If you layout the layout managers do their job and pack() the frame you will not have a problem. I already suggested you problem is because you are NOT using pack() and instead you are manually setting the sizes. You don't want to listen to the suggest and your don't want to post a proper `SSCCE` so I can't help.

Comment: set a background color like RED for fieldpanel, then you can see the problem

Comment: I've solved the problem. It was causing the gridbaglayout. I don't know why but the gridbaglayout put gaps around the field of buttons. I'm using now gridlayout without frame.pack and it works fine. There is only one disadvantage with gridlayout if I change the quantity of buttons it would change also the size automatically (then the buttons are fat or thin but not symmetric and frame.pack() doesn't solve that. It guarantees only that alle subcomponents are in the visible part of the frame). Maybe you can tell me why gridbaglayout has gaps.